# How do I join multiple lines to a single one if the page is viewed on mobile?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Twitter Bootstrap (3.3.X), I want to display these lines on desktop:

> Some info
>   Some more info
>   Even more stuff

And the same on mobile view should display as (pipes as in literal character, not separate blocks if possible):

> Some info | Some more info | Even more stuff

This would be on the right side of a div defined with `col-md-8`, or on a single line above the div if it's on mobile.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `:after` pseudo class and `display: inline-block`

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/393/)**

```css
@media(max-width: 768px) {
  p {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  p:not(:last-child):after {
    content: " |";
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Some info</p>
<p>Some more info</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
```

Comment: If you are using `col-md-8` breaking point is `992px` just so you know.

Comment: Thanks, was wondering why did it flow into the main content between 768 and that 992 width.

Answer (score 1):

Optionally if you are using Twitter Bootstrap 3 you can make use of the  [*visible-*-**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) classes which will let you hide or show content depending on the screen size.

[Example Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z1hf6nz2/2/)

So you could use

```
<p class="custom-menu">
Some info
<span class="visible-md-inline visible-sm-inline visible-xs-inline">/</span>
</p>
<p class="custom-menu">
Some more info
<span class="visible-md-inline visible-sm-inline visible-xs-inline">/</span>
</p>
<p class="custom-menu">
Even more stuff
<span class="visible-md-inline visible-sm-inline visible-xs-inline">/</span>
</p>
```

You could even change the "/" character for a glyphicon o another kind of code.

and for CSS

```
/*Medium Media*/
@media (max-width:1199px) {
  p.custom-menu{display: inline;}
}

/*Small Media*/
@media (max-width:991px) {
  p.custom-menu{display: inline;}
}

/*Extra small Media*/
@media (max-width: 768px){
  p.custom-menu{display: inline;}
}
```

Choose whichever media query suits your needs the best.